# Can't get Android audio file to loop

Tags: java, android, loops, audio

The file plays when the button is hit, but I'd like it to loop indefinitely. The following code DOESN'T work. Everything I'm seeing says create media player, set looping to true, then it starts. Does a "prepare" line need to be thrown in there to? if so, how?

```
final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound4);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();

      }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the setLooping after start.

```
mp.setLooping(true) after mp.start();

final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound4);                
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
    }
 });
```